# angular element addClass active fails

Tags: angularjs, class, addition

on my page I´ve loaded angular and bootstrap. On default loading the panel "#default" is active. In an other case the page get a variable ("name") with. This variable is a string which identifies an other panel. Finally this name panel should be shown. In the code below the remove works but the add not.

```
if (name) {

 angular.element("#deault").removeClass("active");
 angular.element(document.querySelector("#some-other")).addClass("active");

 angular.element("#other-"+name).attr("aria-expanded"));

 angular.element("#other-"+name).attr("aria-expanded", true)
 document.getElementById("#other-"+name).click()

         }else{
           log('no Id "#other-"+name existent')
         }
        log('test')
      }
```

Comment: Is this in a directive or a controller?

Comment: Using Angular like jQuery - you are missing the point of Angular.

Comment: did you check if `angular.element(document.querySelector("#some-other"))` select any DOM element?

Comment: and you should not use angular like jquery. Usually in this case, you should set up your logic in your controller, and use `ng-class` to dynamically add or remove class

Comment: @rrd It´s in the surrounding controller at the end

Comment: You can't access DOM elements from the controller; like Z-Banger says below in his answer, and Zhiliang comments above, the best way is to use the ng-class.

Comment: @ZhiliangTakutoXing Yes. If I c&p it in the browser console it works..

Comment: @rrd but why can I remove a class if I cant access the element?

Comment: @dfsq I dont get you, can you be more specific?

Answer (score 2):

I'm replying because I'm assuming you want to highlight an "active" element.

In angular there's ng-class directive where you can assign class to an element based on a condition.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: The problem with ngClass (I think) is that I need to select 1 out of x elements (which get createt by ng-repeat) by a given string (name). If I insert  ng-class="{active: name}", every element gets activated.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding right but this is what I was thinking about. https://plnkr.co/edit/kS54dLto5OB9WzEewpFp?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

based on your comment, I think it doesn't work because when you try to addClass, the DOM is not ready yet. so try this:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    angular.element(document.querySelector("#some-other")).addClass("active");
});
```

## update

based on your comment I think you should just simply do this

on the `other-panel` DOM element add ng-class like

```
<div id="other-panel" ng-class="{active: name}">
...
</div>
```

in your controller

```
$scope.name = name   #this name should be the name you used in your old code, I guess you get it from $location service
```

Comment: I thought too but even $(document).ready(setTimeout(function(name), 3000)) dont work.

Comment: is the other panel decided dynamically after the DOM is ready?

Comment: basically where did you place this trunk of code and where is the `name `coming from?

Comment: The default panel is allways there. The other panels are created with an ng-repeat. The name variable is set on the server by converting the url. The code I posted above is in a function at the bottom in the controller. I called the function on document ready and as ng-init in a <div> after the panel creation.

Comment: if you have to read the `name` from your backend server, you have to do addClass in the success callback of the request

Comment: I think u got me wrong. I dont use $http. I load the whole page in one. If i order the index, it should load default but if  I order index?a=b I want the panel b to be visible and the default panel hidden.

Comment: Adding  ng-class="{active: contentrequest}" dont work because its in an ng-repeat. It results that every panel get the active class and the structure breaks. The name is already in the $scope but I dont use the location service.